# Login with Google in Laravel using Postman

Tags: laravel, postman, access-token

I am new to laravel and making a login with the Google module in Laravel using Postman. I've successfully generated a Google access token. But how to make the whole module of login with Google in Postman? and Can we use that access token in other modules?

Comment: you need to pass email id for a request param and then write verification code and after successfully verification you can pass response success or failure,

Comment: https://laravel-news.com/google-api-socialite

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible with Postman.
there are two things will be possible

1. You can configure your app with Google and send information to server (Database) through API.
2. or you can create a webpage and there you have to create a setup to login with google and save information in database and send success or failure in form of response